# Wordpress contactform7 how to pass info to email?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created custom checkbox in contactform7. It looks great, you can check checkbox, but doesn`t send information to ant email after submition. Any ideas how to pass it?
Code for the checkbox:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-services">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"class="custom-control-input"> Checkbox text
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label custom-control-description"></span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

Comment: It's not possibl.

Answer (score 0):

The input is missing the `name=""` parameter.

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-services">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox" class="custom-control-input"> Checkbox text
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label custom-control-description"></span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

Now you can get the checkbox value in the mail editor with `[text_checkbox]`